# Java/Android How to call an activity into a method?

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, oncreate

How do i call on a seperate activity within a method:

For example:

```
private void startApp() {
    Patient_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I want this Button to go to an Detailed_ModeActivity
            // This is how i Am doing it right now, but it comes out with an
            // error
            Intent b = new Intent(this, Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
        }
    });

}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.
The Button was declared in the `onCreate` method

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also can you show us the creation of Patient_Button in onCreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` refers to an `View.OnClickListener` object which doesn't have `startActivity()` method and cannot be passed to an `Intent`. You need to call `startActivity()` on a Context (e.g. an Activity). Let's say your code is in the `MainActivity` class. Like this:

```
Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
Intent b = new Intent(v.getContext(), Detailed_ModeActivity.class);
startActivity(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

First up, make sure Detailed_ModeActivity extends Activity.
Secondly you need to add the activity class to the manifest.xml file if you haven't already.